# PHP html_entity_decode Doesn't Decode Entity as Expected?

Tags: php, html-entities

In the following code:

```
$string1 = "function doesn&apos;t work as expected";
$string2 = html_entity_decode($string1);
```

$string2 still contains:

```
 &apos;
```

...after the call to html_entity_decode().

I've checked other SO threads on this topic, but haven't yet found the answer. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [default flags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) for `html_entity_decode` do not include single quotes. Try updating your flags argument to include `ENT_QUOTES` and `ENT_HTML5`:

```
$string1 = "function doesn&apos;t work as expected";
echo $string2 = html_entity_decode($string1, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML5);
// function doesn't work as expected
```